# How to find page load completed

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

We are working on an Open Source Chrome extension: [Digital Assistant Client](https://github.com/kcramakrishna/Digital_Assistant_Client)

We have a script which invokes clicks on web pages.
We record a sequence of clicks as a 'flow' or 'task'. i.e. After the first click is invoked, we wait 5 s for the page to load and then invoke the 2nd click.

```
setTimeout(function(){UDAPluginSDK.showhtml();}, 5000);
```

Now, instead of waiting for 5s, we want to explore if we can invoke the 2nd click as soon as the page is loaded. We tried using "onPageLoad" but we realised that this does not work for modern single page (responsive) applications. i.e. we don't know when the js has finished executing.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   setTimeout(function (){
      UDAPluginSDK.modifybodyhtml();
   },2000);
});
```

Comment: Try checking out below MDN docs.. might help -            https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: Hi Javvy,

I am already using load event but that doesn't give me xmlhttp request completed status